# Can't get element of web browser document

Tags: c#, html, webbrowser-control

I'm doing some webscraping from a WinForms-Application. Here's a snippet from the browser document I want to scrape from:

```
<div class="div1" id="id1" data-on-choice="asdf">
<h4>Target:</h4>                                                            
<table class="table1" style="width: 100%;">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td>
            <div class="div2">
                <label>aa</label>
                <label>ab</label>
                <label>ac</label>
            </div>                                                                  
            <div class="div3" id="id2">
                <span class="span1" role="status" aria-live="polite"></span>
            </div>
            <a class="anchor1" style="display: inline;" href="#"></a>                       
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="div4">
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

The HtmlElement I want to get and click on would be the anchor "anchor1". Note that I have done similar stuff numerous times, but I just can't seem to get this particular element. Even when I print the InnerHtml of all anchor-elements of my document, there is not a line for this element.

Html-Agility-Pack is not an option, as my application is too big to recode. The html is not under my control, so assigning id's to elements, ... is not an option either.

In my opinion this should do the trick, it is not working though:

```
HtmlElement elementToClick = browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")
         .Cast<HtmlElement>()
         .FirstOrDefault(m => m.GetAttribute("class") == "anchor1");
elementToClick.InvokeMember("click");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since class is a special name it doesn't return the value for that. You should use **className** instead. Snippet below worked for me:

```
var elementToClick = browser.Document
            .GetElementsByTagName("a")
            .Cast<HtmlElement>()
            .FirstOrDefault(m => m.GetAttribute("className") == "anchor1");
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you explain why class doesn't work like other attributes?

Comment: That's how they implemented it. They mentioned it in the [SetAttribute documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.setattribute.aspx): "To set the class attribute on an HtmlElement , you must refer to the attribute as className when specifying the first argument to SetAttribute". I guess they should have noted it for the GetAttribute as well

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke click on your required **a** tag by invoking the javascript like this:

```
browser.InvokeScript("document.querySelector('a.anchor1').click()");
```

Your invoked script will run on the web document loaded on the your web browser control.

For more info on InvokeScript, refer to
[WebBrowser.InvokeScript Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc452443(v=vs.110).aspx)